# vb.net 2005 : crystal reports application or windows application to generate pdfs?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2005

I currently have a simple crystal reports application which generates a crystal report and in the built in viewer provided by VS2005.   There is a drop down where you can select options to change the criteria of the report.  I wish to convert this app to a windows executable which will take all those select options and generates pdfs based on the crystal report.  the executable will be triggered by windows task scheduler...or maybe command line app?

Obviously this will be somewhat of a re-write.  What would be the best way to start this as?  a crystal report application or a windows application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using VS2005 and creating a command line app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CrystalHelper. One of the many things it provides, is the ability to take an existing Crystal Report and export it to PDF. Especially helpful in Web applications, because the clients don't need a Crystal viewer - just a PDF viewer, which almost everyone already has!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CrystalHelper.aspx